# Export ‘epiR" Output to Tables

Tags: r, flextable, gtsummary

Good Morning,

i am using the "epiR" packages to assess test accuracy.

https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/epiR/html/epi.tests.html

```
## Generate a data set listing test results and true disease status:
dis <- c(rep(1, times = 744), rep(0, times = 842))
tes <- c(rep(1, times = 670), rep(0, times = 74), 
   rep(1, times = 202), rep(0, times = 640))
dat.df02 <- data.frame(dis, tes)

tmp.df02 <- dat.df02 %>%
  mutate(dis = factor(dis, levels = c(1,0), labels = c("Dis+","Dis-"))) %>%
  mutate(tes = factor(tes, levels = c(1,0), labels = c("Test+","Test-"))) %>%
  group_by(tes, dis) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
tmp.df02

## View the data in conventional 2 by 2 table format:
pivot_wider(tmp.df02, id_cols = c(tes), names_from = dis, values_from = n)

rval.tes02 <- epi.tests(tmp.df02, method = "exact", digits = 2, 
   conf.level = 0.95)
summary(rval.tes02)
```

The data type is listed as "epi.test". I would like to export the summary statistics to a table (i.e. gtsummary or flextable).

As summary is a function of base R, I am struggling to do this. Can anyone help? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The `epi.tests` function has been edited so it writes the results out to a data frame (instead of a list). This will simplify export to `gtsummary` or `flextable`. `epiR` version 2.0.50 to be uploaded to CRAN shortly.

Answer (score -1):

This was not quite as straight forward as I expected.

It appears that `summary()` when applied to an object `x` of class `epi.tests` simply prints `x$details`.  `x$details` is a list of `data.frame`s with statistic names as row names.  That last bit makes things slightly more complicated than they would otherwise have been.

A potential tidyverse solution is

```
library(tidyverse)

lapply(
  names(rval.tes02$detail), 
  function(x) {
    as_tibble(rval.tes02$detail[[x]]) %>% 
      add_column(statistic=x, .before=1)
  }
) %>% 
bind_rows()
# A tibble: 18 × 4
   statistic     est   lower  upper
   <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 ap         0.550   0.525   0.574
 2 tp         0.469   0.444   0.494
 3 se         0.901   0.877   0.921
 4 sp         0.760   0.730   0.789
 5 diag.ac    0.826   0.806   0.844
 6 diag.or   28.7    21.5    38.2  
 7 nndx       1.51    1.41    1.65 
 8 youden     0.661   0.607   0.710
 9 pv.pos     0.768   0.739   0.796
10 pv.neg     0.896   0.872   0.918
11 lr.pos     3.75    3.32    4.24 
12 lr.neg     0.131   0.105   0.163
13 p.rout     0.450   0.426   0.475
14 p.rin      0.550   0.525   0.574
15 p.tpdn     0.240   0.211   0.270
16 p.tndp     0.0995  0.0789  0.123
17 p.dntp     0.232   0.204   0.261
18 p.dptn     0.104   0.0823  0.128
```

Which is a tibble containing the same information as `summary(rval.tes02)`, which you should be able to pass on to `gtsummary` or `flextable`.  Unusually, the broom package doesn't have a `tidy()` verb for `epi.tests` objects.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm very grateful. Unfortunately, I do have problems to run the code (since the update). Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..1$value` <character> and `..2$value` <double>.
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% bind_rows()
 2. dplyr::bind_rows(.)
 5. vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id). Do you have an idea how to convert the dataframe to gtsummary or flextable. Thank you very much

Comment: According to @user17535591’s comment, the authors of epiR have done the work for you. I would wait until the update is available on CRAN and use that. The update should make my solution redundant.

Comment: I am sorry Limey for the questions. Since the update (yesterday) of epiR your code is not working anymore and it gives the error. Can you tell me how i can pass the "data frame" to flextable? Thank you very much